# If $\text{char}(F)\nmid[E:F]$ then $E/F$ is separable

Tags: extension-field, separable-extension

> Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension. Suppose $p=\text{char}(F),n=[E:F]$ and $p\nmid n$. Prove that $E/F$ is separable.

I don't really have an attempt just a few observarions like if $p=0$ is we're done. So suppose $p>0$. Of course $p$ is a prime and we have $n=ap+b$ with $b\ne 0$.

Comment: How is the degree of a field extension defined? Also, there is a result that links the separability of a polynomial with the gcd of it and its formal derivative.

Comment: $[E:F]$ is defined to be $\dim_F(E)$.

Comment: For $f \in F[x]$ then $f' = 0$ iff $f = g(x^p), g \in F[x]$. Also $\gcd(f,f') $ divides $f$. Thus $f$ irreducible non-separable implies $\gcd(f,f') = f, f'=0$ and $f = g(x^p)$ and $p |\deg(f)$. With $p^m$ the largest power such that $f = G(x^{p^m})$ then $G$ is irreducible separable and the roots of $f$ are the $a_j^{1/p^m})$ with $a_j$ the roots of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in E$. Then the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (let's call it $f$) is $[F(\alpha):F]$ which divides $n$ and hence not divisible by $p$. From here we can easily get that the derivative of $f$ is non-zero. Since $f$ is irreducible over $F$ and $0\leq deg(f')<deg(f)$ we conclude that $\gcd(f,f')=1$ and hence $f$ is separable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: It is enough to show that if $F=E(\alpha)$ and $p$ does not divide $[F:E]$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is separable. What are the non-separable irreducible polynomials?

Comment: I don't know all of them. I just know 1 polynomial like that: $x^p-\alpha^p\in \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ but I'm not sure is relevant.

Comment: @J.Doe: Part of the exercise is *finding* all of them (or at least narrowing them down to ones of degree divisible by $p$).